# REST based service on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, database

I have never before created a REST based service. I am about to create a simple apps for the iPhone which needs to store data and I want to consume the data by using a REST API. Do you think this is worthed or should I as well do a query to the DB? What sort of DB/language do usually iPhone developers use for their application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the iPhone includes SQLite which can store your data locally.  If you need to query a system on a server, then you need some method of exposing your data and performing operations against it.  Using a RESTful api with something like JSON is a relatively common method for this.

For the database, it depends on your needs, if you need a true relational database then something like MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc. will work.  You can also look at Google's BigTable or Amazon's SimpleDB to store data for non-relational data stores, and write your RESTful services on those.

This article has an example of integrating the iPhone with Flikr using their REST services and JSON.

http://iosdevelopertips.com/networking/iphone-json-flickr-tutorial-part-1.html

Comment: How complex is it to create a rest web service from a database?

Comment: There are some apps that will generate this for you based on your database model.  It's a matter of using what you're comfortable with.  For example NetBeans has an option to generate a RESTful service from a MySQL database.  Link to article: http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/rest-mysql.html  Screenshot: http://netbeans.org/images_www/articles/60/websvc/mysql/sakila-entity-classes-from-database.png

Comment: Just wanted to know, what database do iOS dev use for their apps?

Comment: I've queried from SQL Server, MySQL and SQLite.  It's really up to you and what you're comfortable with to fit your requirements.  I don't know if there's a "most popular".  The nice thing about about building RESTful (or any web service) is the clients can be agnostic.  Mobile Phones, Web Browsers, PC's, iPads, PlayStations.  I personally build my web sites and services with Python, Django and MySQL.  In the past I've done this with PhP on MySQL as well as ASP.NET MVC with SQL Server.  I've found Django and Python on MySQL a solid place to start.

Answer (score 1):

I think [RESTKit](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit) provides seamless integration with SQLite in addition to being a nice REST client. There's also [RESTframework](https://github.com/ivasic/RESTframework) if you're looking for something simple to use.